# The New York Times API with R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get articles' information using The New York Times API. The csv file I get doesn't reflect my filter query. For example, I restricted the source to 'The New York Times', but the file I got contains other sources also. 
I would like to ask you why the filter query doesn't work.

Here's the code.

```
if (!require("jsonlite")) install.packages("jsonlite")
library(jsonlite)

api = "apikey"

nytime = function () {
  url = paste('http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?',
              '&fq=source:',("The New York Times"),'AND type_of_material:',("News"),
              'AND persons:',("Trump, Donald J"),
              '&begin_date=','20160522&end_date=','20161107&api-key=',api,sep="")
  #get the total number of search results
  initialsearch = fromJSON(url,flatten = T)
  maxPages = round((initialsearch$response$meta$hits / 10)-1)

  #try with the max page limit at 10
  maxPages = ifelse(maxPages >= 10, 10, maxPages)

  #creat a empty data frame
  df = data.frame(id=as.numeric(),source=character(),type_of_material=character(),
                  web_url=character())

  #save search results into data frame
  for(i in 0:maxPages){
    #get the search results of each page
    nytSearch = fromJSON(paste0(url, "&page=", i), flatten = T) 
    temp = data.frame(id=1:nrow(nytSearch$response$docs),
                      source = nytSearch$response$docs$source, 
                      type_of_material = nytSearch$response$docs$type_of_material,
                      web_url=nytSearch$response$docs$web_url)
    df=rbind(df,temp)
    Sys.sleep(5) #sleep for 5 second
  }
  return(df)
}

dt = nytime()
write.csv(dt, "trump.csv")
```

Here's the csv file I got.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to put the () inside the quotes, not outside. Like this:

```
  url = paste('http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?',
              '&fq=source:',"(The New York Times)",'AND type_of_material:',"(News)",
              'AND persons:',"(Trump, Donald J)",
              '&begin_date=','20160522&end_date=','20161107&api-key=',api,sep="")
```

https://developer.nytimes.com/docs/articlesearch-product/1/overview